# Access a web application running on one server from a different web application running on another server

Tags: java, web-applications, web

I have developed a web application (say webapp1) running on server (say server1 ).
I have another web application (say webapp2) running on different server(say server2).

Only registered users on webapp1 must be able to log in to webapp2 using username and password from webapp1 session.
webapp1 using active directory to authenticate users.  Some users of webapp1 can access webapp2 by internally going through active directory.

I want to access webapp1 fron webapp2. How can I do that?

Comment: Please read the FAQ before asking questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I think you question is something like this. You have two web apps and when a request comes in your first webapp1 does some processing and other part to be done by second webapp.

This can be done by redirecting/forwarding the request to the second webapp, let the second webapp complete the remaining part of work and return it to user or to the first webapp again.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to create an API to do this.

See a similar question (for PHP but the basic concept still applies): [create api using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906255/create-api-using-php)

Build RESTful web services with Java technology:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-rest/index.html